# Add class to several elements in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have switch that need's to add or remove class. In my `.ts` file I have:

```js
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [
    "InformationOne",
    "InformationTwo",
    "InformationThree",
    "InformationFour",
    "InformationSwitchOne",
    "InformationSwitchTwo"
  ];

  private InformationOne: HTMLElement[];
  private InformationTwo: HTMLElement[];
  private InformationThree: HTMLElement[];
  private InformationFour: HTMLElement[];
  private InformationSwitchOne: HTMLInputElement;
  private InformationSwitchTwo: HTMLInputElement;

  switchInformation(): void {
    if (this.InformationSwitchOne.checked) {
        this.InformationOne.forEach((item) => { item.classList.remove("d-none"); });
        this.InformationTwo.forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); });
        this.InformationThree.forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); });
        this.InformationFour.forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); });
    } else if (this.InformationSwitchTwo.checked) {
        this.InformationTwo.forEach((item) => { item.classList.remove("d-none"); });
        this.InformationOne.forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); });
        this.InformationThree.forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); });
        this.InformationFour.forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); });
    }
  }
}
```

Now question is, how to make lines below more elegant? Is there a way to grab this three elements and perform on them `classList.add` rather then getting them one by one?

```js
this.InformationTwo.forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); });
this.InformationThree.forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); });
this.InformationFour.forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); })
```

Comment: How are you using `.forEach` in `this.InformationOne.forEach` when `this.InformationOne` is a singular object? It's typed as `HTMLInputElement`, _not_ `HTMLInputElement[]` - so how is tsc even compiling this?

Comment: My bad, while copying I made typo. Code is fully working and compiling.

Comment: Is this code within a `class` type?

Comment: I noticed that in _both_ `if` branches you call `classList.add("d-none")` for `InformationFour` - is that intentional?

Comment: It is inside `export default class extends Controller`. If goes for `InformationSwitchOne`, `InformationSwitchTwo`, `InformationSwitchThree`, `InformationSwitchFour`. In each if I just wan't to remove class `d-none` to element that is checked and add `d-none` to all other elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe in your last comment, you basically have a mapping of lists and switches and want to show the items for each switch, correct?

Then you can do something like this:

```js
switchInformation(): void {
  // a mapping which items are shown for which switch
  const mapping = [
    // [HTMLInputElement, HTMLElement[]]
    [this.InformationSwitchOne, this.InformationOne],
    [this.InformationSwitchTwo, this.InformationTwo],
    [this.InformationSwitchThree, this.InformationThree],
    [this.InformationSwitchFour, this.InformationFour],
  ];

  for (const [{ checked }, items] of mapping) {
    for (const item of items) {
      // toggle "d-none" based on wether the switch is checked or not.
      item.classList.toggle("d-none", !checked);
    }
  }
}
```

And if the mapping doesn't change you can even move that out of the function.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified:

```js
this.InformationTwo  .forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); });
this.InformationThree.forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); });
this.InformationFour .forEach((item) => { item.classList.add("d-none"); })
```

...to this:

```js
const all = this.InformationTwo.concat( this.InformationThree ).concat( this.InformationFour );
for( const inp of all ) {
    inp.classList.toggle( 'd-none', /*force:*/ this.InformationSwitchOne.checked );
}
```